# Is it possible to combine animations?

Tags: android, lottie

I'm exploring the possibility of combining two animations into a single one for a `LottieAnimationView`. With this we could ideally create dynamic animations by splitting long animations into sections and building on the fly. Does anyone know if this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use `setminandsetMinAndMaxProgress(0,0.5f)` you can call that your first animation and `setminandsetMinAndMaxProgress(0.5f,1f)` that your second animation